# chrome --headless sometimes empty pdf

Tags: php, google-chrome-headless

I devoleped a headless browser printing process that sometimes (< 1%) generates a blank pdf. the called url is normally used inside a greater html5app to show the user some printable pages.

the backend is done in php7 on linux.

```
$chromeBinary = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable';
$pdfRenderUrl = $baseUrl . ($json->{'printPath'});
$fileName = 'print_' . $json->{'jpgName'} . '.pdf';
$outputDirectory = '/data/projects/xxx/htdocs/xxxx/' . $fileName;

$command = sprintf(
                '%s --headless --virtual-time-budget=8000 --Cache-Control=no-store --print-to-pdf=%s %s',
                escapeshellarg($chromeBinary),
                escapeshellarg($outputDirectory),
                escapeshellarg($pdfRenderUrl)
            );
```

exec( $command  );

ok, there's only one ajax call inside the url, but this content isn't used in the headless printing. actually I dind't now how to find the error. is there a way to delay the printing after loading the url? I read that --virtual-time-budget is only a timeout for the loaded event!?! how can I make an enternal loaded event after a few seconds?

Comment: Is using NodeJS an option? Because then you could use the [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which might give you more control over the process. Even if NodeJS is not an option, their repo might have some useful clues.

Comment: I will have a look at the repos, but there's no nodejs option...

Comment: Hi there @bluelemonade, did you ever figured out what was going on? Or you had to find a workaround? Thank you!

Comment: no, I did a workaround by checking the pdf size, when its lower then xx kb then retry...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @bluelemonade! That's what we thought... We'll do the same.

Comment: I find this is caused by the `--virtual-time-budget` option. There may be other effects to not specifying it, but removing that flag fixes the blank PDF problem for me.